# Cannot test custom hooks with React 18 and renderHook from testing-library/react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I have a cutom hook that makes an API call on mount and handles state (isLoading, isError, data, refetch);

The hook is quite simple:

```
    const useFetch = (endpoint, options) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(true);

    const triggerSearch = () => {
        setTrigger(!trigger);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(
                    `${process.env.API_URL}${endpoint}`
                );
                const json = await response.json();
                setData(json);
                setIsLoading(false);
            } catch (error) {
                setError(error);
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [endpoint, trigger]);
    return {
        data,
        isLoading,
        error,
        triggerSearch,
    };
};
```

When trying to test the hook, I'm using jest and testing-library/react.

With react 18, the react-hooks from testing-library is no longer supported so I cannot use awaitForNextUpdate from renderHook as it doesn't return it.

Instead, we should use act and waitFor - which I have done and tests pass.

The problem is that I get the following error

> Warning: An update to TestComponent inside a test was not wrapped in
> act(...).
>
> ```
> When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
> ```

```
test("should make an API call on mount", async () => {
    const hook = renderHook(() => useFetch("/api"));

    await act(async () => {
        await waitFor(() => expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
    });

    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    expect(getAccessTokenSilently).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    expect(hook.result.current.data).toEqual({ message: "Test" });
    expect(hook.result.current.isLoading).toEqual(false);
    expect(hook.result.current.error).toEqual(null);
});
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction? I have tried removing all of the assertions and just calling renderHook, which also results in the same error.

Comment: Hey I'm finding the same issue now that I've updated to React 18 and the latest RTL `13.3` and jest `5.16.5`. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the way I resolved the issue was to include everything that calls setState function inside async act (including the initialization of renderhook, because it calls the api via useEffect):

```
  describe("useFetch", () => {
    test("should make a call to the API and return the message", async () => {
        let hook;
        await act(async () => {
            hook = renderHook(() => useFetch("/api"));
        });
        const { result } = hook;
        expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(getAccessTokenSilently).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(result.current.data).toEqual({ message: "Test" });
        expect(result.current.isLoading).toEqual(false);
        expect(result.current.error).toEqual(null);
    });
});
```

Oh and make sure you are importing act from `@testing-library/react`

Comment: any idea, how to use it with the `wrapper` component, getting an error as "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined" when using Redux provider as the wrapper component?

Comment: This is the wrong approach:

- You should never need to wrap testing-library methods in act(), including `renderHook` and `waitFor`

- In async tests, your callback is probably happening on a tick that's not during rendering the hook or taking action, so you should do something like `await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.data).toEqual({ message: 'Text' }))`

Answer (score 1):

Using act to call testing library methods [is discouraged](https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/blob/main/docs/rules/no-unnecessary-act.md).

It's better to call the callback itself.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work.

```
test("should make an API call on mount", async () => {
  const hook = renderHook(() => useFetch("/api"));

  // remove the act method
  // you are not triggering an user action
  await waitFor(() => expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));

  expect(getAccessTokenSilently).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  expect(hook.result.current.data).toEqual({ message: "Test" });
  expect(hook.result.current.isLoading).toEqual(false);
  expect(hook.result.current.error).toEqual(null);
});
```

Or you could try advancing timers:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  // we're using fake timers because we don't want to
  // wait a full second for this test to run.
  jest.useFakeTimers();
});

afterAll(() => {
  jest.useRealTimers();
});

test("should make an API call on mount", () => {
  const hook = renderHook(() => useFetch("/api"));

  //advance timers by 1 second
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);

  // remove the act method
  // you are not triggering an user action
  expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  expect(getAccessTokenSilently).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  expect(hook.result.current.data).toEqual({ message: "Test" });
  expect(hook.result.current.isLoading).toEqual(false);
  expect(hook.result.current.error).toEqual(null);
});
```

In my case I was using a click event to update the DOM and I had to use `act` during the `fireEvent` click event like so:

```
 it('open toggler assessment modal when clicking card button', async () => {
    renderTeacherAssessments();

    const assessmentCard = screen.getAllByTestId('assessment-card');
    const assessmentCardButton = assessmentCard[0].querySelector('button');

    act(() => {
      assessmentCardButton.click();
    });

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByTestId('confirm-modal')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
```

I've read in other posts regarding to the `act` warning where most of them would be fixed by just using `await waitFor...` wrapping the `expect` method, but now for React18 and the latest RTL I'm not sure that still works.